# Remove element from html string (What is wrong with this script)

Tags: jquery

```
script = "<div><p>sss</p></div>";
$(script).find('p').remove();
console.log($(script));
```

I want to remove the p element from script
​Why the p element still available?

Answer (score 3):

## Update

This is how you can check it:

```
script = "<div><p>sss</p>i am a div</div>";
$(script).contents().find('p').remove();
console.log($(script).contents().find('p'));
```

**Output:**

```
[]
```

Try using [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/):

> Description: Get the children of each element in the set of matched
>   elements, including text and comment nodes.

```
script = "<div><p>sss</p></div>";
a = $(script).contents().find('p').remove();
console.log($(script));
console.log(a);
```

### [Working Example](http://jsbin.com/upalob)

Comment: @Snoob: That's because you are checking wrong variable, see updated answer.

Comment: @Sarfraz I think `.filter('p')` is quite the same as `.contents().find('p')`, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()` instead of `find()`:

```
$(script).filter('p').remove();
```